# How to add applicative effects to a monoid?

Tags: haskell

How can I change following code so that each element in `Maybe` monoid element takes also two arguments (so it would become "double" reader applicative)?

```
g :: (Monoid a, IsString a) => [Maybe a] -> Maybe a
g = foldr (<>) (Just "")
```

So that result would be of type:

```
g2 :: (Monoid a, IsString a) => [b -> c -> Maybe a] -> b -> c -> Maybe a
```

I guess I could lift `<>` twice:

```
> :t (liftA2 $ liftA2 (<>))
(liftA2 $ liftA2 (<>))
  :: (Monoid c, Applicative f1, Applicative f) =>
     f (f1 c) -> f (f1 c) -> f (f1 c)
```

But I'm stuck trying to compose it with `foldr` to get the type signature I want.

Comment: Are you just wanting to turn `[b -> c -> Maybe a]` into `[Maybe a]` by applying the `b` and `c` to each element, then `foldr (<>) (Just "")` over it?  If so, why not just `g2 xs b c = g $ map (($ (b, c)) . uncurry) xs`?

Comment: Or is the goal to have `(Monoid a, IsString a, Applicative f, Applicative g) => g (b -> c -> f a) -> b -> c -> f (g a)`?

Comment: Getting the same signature does not tell us what the intended functionality is. `g2 xs b c = traverse (($ c).($ b)) xs` and `g2' xs b c = foldr (<>) (Just "") $ map (($ c).($ b)) xs` behave differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it

```
g2 x y = g $ ($ y) <$> ($ x) <$> theList
```